# Macbook Pro A1708 Intel i5 won't update the firmware and remains in black screen

Tags: macbook-pro, firmware

I have a 13" Macbook Pro 2016 non-touchbar with Intel i5 processor on it. The trouble with it that i can't get its firmware updated from 205.0.0.0.0 to the latest 499.40.2.0.0

The laptop was liquid damaged.Ii replaced the battery and keyboard together. The battery was used and came together with keyboard. There was no other problems seen when it works.

So far this is what i tried

-tried on a identical genuine apple ssd
-disconnected the battery.
-reset nvram
-tried on a 3rd party sabrent ssd
-installed all osxs available for this Mac from High Sierra to Ventura.

All but Ventura successfully installs. All finished installing but goes to black screen at first reboot after the first online update downloaded and installed. It goes to black screen because the online update contains firmware update and the firmware update does not initiate. At this moment I can bring the laptop back alive pressing Shift Option Command and POWER buttons several times.

Maybe the boot ROM attempts to update from a very low version to something much greater for it to handle. Can anyone send me a firmware update that is not the latest available but something in between 205... and 499...?

Comment: I'm not exactly clear what you've done. Have you tried installing Ventura on the internal drive, using an installer media disk or booting from an external? In my experience, any liquid damaged Mac will usually stop working at some point.

Comment: i can't install ventura. installation stops at black screen at first ever restart and brings black screen. you can see a firmware update error if you interrupt the lack screen by pressing SHIFT OPTION COMMAND POWER. ventura installation never continues from that error. you can install oother osxs but again they bring black screen once you attempt doing an online update which contains thhat critical firmware update. i installed ventura on an identical laptop and swapped the disks. now i have working ventura but i diisabled online updates just in case and firmware remains old.

Comment: i even managed to install an operating system into an external drive with genuine macbook drive in it. once you do the online update, you get black screen.

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac? Can you use Apple Configurator app to install the Firmware?

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple, the 2016 MBP is not compatible with Ventura. (2017 MBP is earliest.)

https://support.apple.com/HT213264

I would use the freeware app SilentKnight, which shows what firmware updates are available, and will try to install them.

https://eclecticlight.co/lockrattler-systhist/

Otherwise, use Apple's Configurator app. You'll need to run this on another Mac, with the target Mac connected by Thunderbolt/USB.

However, a Mac that's had a liquid spill cannot be relied on.

Comment: thanks for reply. i installed ventura on another macbook and installed the disk in the problematic laptop to work. but ventura is not the problem. I installed hig sierra, mojave, catalina, big sur, monterey on this pc without any issue but once you download your first update and restart the pc it hangs in black screen. this is due to unsuccessfull attempt to install the firmware embedded in the software updates.

Comment: @MustafaGelgec So, any automatic update will fail?

Comment: thanks again, tried silentknight, same result. apple configurator doesn't support mine. requires 2018 macbooks. yes, any update fails to install and ending up in black screen. update continues once i interrupt the black screen with SHIFT OPTION COMMAND and POWER. it just don't want to install firmware update that embedded into online updates.